# Jquery on method firing only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem here, i want to add and remove a class to a element and I am using on() method to handle the click event on body. The code works on the first click but after the first click it wont handle the event anymore!
Below is the code:

```
    $('body').on('click', '#cshero-menu-mobile .cms-icon-menu', function(){

        var navigation = $(this).parents().find('#cshero-header-navigation');

        if(!navigation.hasClass('collapse')){
           navigation.addClass('collapse');
        }else if(navigation.hasClass('collapse')){
           navigation.removeClass('collapse');
        }
    });
```

This is a problem I am having with menu icon that appears on mobile and tablets and I want to open and close the menu when clicked!
I tried putting an alert just below the first line of code and it will alerts only once! Any help is appreciated!

```
<div id="cshero-header-navigation" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-9 col-lg-9 phones-nav" style="z-index:999999;">
<div class="navigation-main">
    <div class="cshero-navigation-right hidden-xs hidden-sm icon-search-hidden">
        <div class="nav-button-icon">
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
        <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
            <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav-menu menu-main-menu">
                <li>links</li>
                <li>links</li>
                <li>links</li>
                <li>links</li>
                <li>links</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

```
<div id="cshero-menu-mobile" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
     <i class="cms-icon-menu pe-7s-menu"></i>
</div>
```

This is my html code. In mobile view the menu will be opened only once!

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: Try changing the `body` to `document` on first line

Comment: verify if you have an error in the console click on "F12"

Comment: You can toggleClass instead your if else statement
http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: I tried the toggleClass but it will give the same result! Also there isn't any error in the console!
I also tried to change body to document but making this change it wont work after all!

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to **reproduce the problem** -> [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)

Comment: have you tried with other ways to bind the `event`, i.e. the same problem is occurred with other ways?

Comment: I updated the question, maybe i forgot earlier but this problem is caused when i am in mobile view and i have a button that will show and close the menu but it only shows it once!

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is with your code: you forgot to include a **comma** `,` between `#cshero-menu-mobile` and `.cms-icon-menu`. Below is the recommended solution:

```
$('body').on('click', '#cshero-menu-mobile, .cms-icon-menu', function(){

    var navigation = $(this).parents().find('#cshero-header-navigation');

    if(!navigation.hasClass('collapse')){
       navigation.addClass('collapse');
    }else if(navigation.hasClass('collapse')){
       navigation.removeClass('collapse');
    }
});
```

Rather than using `on`, you could simply use the click handler as well like so `$('body').click('#cshero-menu-mobile, .cms-icon-menu', function(){...` which would still work.

From what I can deduce, it would appear that you're trying to imitate [**Bootstrap**'s accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion). I would recommend you use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#cshero-menu-mobile .cms-icon-menu', function(){
    $(this).parents().find('#cshero-header-navigation').toggleClass("collapse")
});
```

Comment: It won't work. As I said, the problem seams to be that the on() method fires just once, it works only in the first click!

Comment: collapse is a bootstrap class

Answer (score 0):

To every one interested, I fixed the problem, just changed the first line from

```
$('body').on('click', '#cshero-menu-mobile, .cms-icon-menu', function(){
```

to

```
$('body').click(function(){
```

this seams to bind the click event directly to body so a simple solution!